# Why use ivars for IBOutlets instead of properties?

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, automatic-ref-counting, ivars

I just started to work on a new project. It has a lot of legacy code and I found the following code

```
@interface WLLeftSideViewController : UIViewController {

@private
    __weak IBOutlet UIButton *_signInButton;
    __weak IBOutlet UIButton *_signOutButton;
    __weak IBOutlet UILabel *_nameLabel;
    __weak IBOutlet UILabel *_emailLabel;
    __weak IBOutlet WLLeftSideMenuView *_tableView;
    __weak IBOutlet UIButton *_settingsButton;

    __weak IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *_heightConstraint;
}
```

I have a couple of doubts:

- What could be the advantage of using private ivars for an IBOutlet?
- Why add the __weak? As I understand in ARC environment ivars are always weak.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The key word here is **legacy**

- No advantages
- All variables (ivars and not) by default is strong.